# Why do we need to put the *.odex files under /system/app even if we already have /data/dalvik-cache?

Tags: android, optimization, virtual-machine, loader, dalvik

For instance, we have `phone.apk` and `phone.odex` under `/system/app`. According to some unofficial documentation, `phone.odex` is used to expedite the process of loading an app. However, why do we not just put `phone.odex` under `/data/dalvik`?

What's more weird is: There exists a file named `system@app@phone@classes.dex` under `/data/dalvik`, when the app is loading, which one takes priority to load, `/system/app/phone.odex` or `/data/dalvik/system@app@phone@classes.dex`?

Is it totally redundant to put `phone.odex` under `/system/app`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `/system/app` directory is read-only on normal (non-developer) devices, and only updated when the system receives an update.  The point of `/system/app/*.odex` is that the .odex file can be delivered as part of a system update, so it doesn't have to be generated on the first post-update boot, and doesn't eat up space on the /data partition.

If the .apk and .odex files are out of sync, the system is not able to overwrite the .odex in `/system/app`, and will try to generate a correct version in `/data/dalvik-cache`.  Normally this will fail, because when .apk and .odex are delivered in pairs, the .apk does not contain a .dex file (it would be redundant to do so).

The .odex in `/system/app` is scanned first, so it essentially takes priority.

Finding a redundant .odex is not expected, and suggests that at some point the device had a `phone.apk` that included a .dex and that did not match the .odex.

Comment: I updated system/priv-app as update will be present in data partition now but android app crashes and takes dex from system partition and keep on crashing with ClassNotFoundException. After crashing first time app goes to old version what was pushed before. any help would be appreciated

Comment: @Godather You should create a new question for this, describing in detail what you're doing and how it's failing. Be sure to specify which version of Android you're working with.

Comment: I am building for L and higher although target and compiled is 23.[link for new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38989406/android-system-app-update-needs-rebooting-device).